# Parse data form page to page using js/jquery

Tags: jquery, html

**page1.js:**

In page1.js, I am getting some large data in r.message object from a callback method,which I am passing to update_page2.html

```
if (r.message != undefined) {
        var data = r.message.last_name; // trying with only one element for sample
        console.log(data);
        window.location = 'update_page2.html?data=' + data;
    }
```

**update_page2.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 function getQueryVariable(variable) {
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var vars = query.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split('=');
        if (decodeURIComponent(pair[0]) == variable) {
            return decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
        }
    }
    console.log('Query variable %s not found', variable);
}

console.log(getQueryVariable('data'));
var d = getQueryVariable('data');
$('[data-fieldname="last_name"]').val(d);
});
```

The above thing works for me as I am passing **only one** value (last_name) 
from page to page2.

**problem 1:** when I pass the entire object(r.message) from page1 to update_page2, in url it shows me `update_page2.html?data=[object%20Object]` correctly, but **can't parse that object** in js. How can I parse that object.

(On **console.log(getQueryVariable('data'))**,the object is looking like a string instead of object)

**problem 2:** If I pass some array elements from page1 to page2, how can I insert those values using data-fieldname on multiple input fields.

Manually I can Insert one by one as:

```
$('[data-fieldname="first_name"]').val(d['first_name']);
$('[data-fieldname="last_name"]').val(d['last_name']);
$('[data-fieldname="mobile_no"]').val(d['mobile_no']);
```

and is there any better way for passing values from page to page.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you pass the object in the url it only writes the result of your object cast to string (that [object%20Object] you see), you need to do:

```
window.location = 'update_page2.html?data=' + JSON.stringify(data)
```

this will pass the object structure as a string ("{test: 'test'}" instead of [object%20Object])

then, to retrieve the data just do JSON.parse(variable)

Also, in my opinion, a more elegant way to do this would be to use localStorage, so that your url doesn't get changed and displays that ugly json, you can do it this way:

```
localStorage.setItem("localstorage_test", JSON.stringify({test:'test', test2:'test2'}));
```

and then, to retrieve it:

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("localstorage_test"))
```

this will work from page to page since the data will be stored in the user's browser (not locally between the scope of the first js)

Comment: Yeah Thanks I found it just an hour and half before. By the way I m struck at problem no:2 ,can you help me in finding a easy solution for that. & is there any other easy solution for passing data page to page